# Fancybox gallery, begin with the last element

Tags: jquery, symfony, fancybox, twig, fancybox-2

I use fancyBox ( http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ ) to display an image gallery with thumbnails, but  my gallery always begin with the last elem

```
{% for pic in property.media.galleryHasMedias %}
  <a class="fancybox-img" href="{% path pic.media, 'reference' %}" rel="gallery" title="image bien">
    {% thumbnail pic.media, 'big' %}
   </a>                
{% endfor %}
```

here is my JS code :

```
$(".fancybox-img").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            title: null,
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 108,
                height  : 72
            },
            overlay : {
                css : {
                    'width' : '900px',
                    'height' : '675px',
                    'background' : 'rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.9)'
                }
            }
        },
        index: 2,
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        beforeClose : function(){
            $("#tabs li:first-child a").trigger('click');
        }
    }).trigger('click');
```

any idea to force fancybox begin with my first image ?

here is fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/willwill/NLbs8/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit explanation about what is happening :

When you do this :

```
$(".fancybox-img").fancybox();
```

... you bind fancybox to ALL elements with class `fancybox-img`

OK yes I know that, but how does it actually work?

- the script finds the first element with class `fancybox-img` and binds it to fancybox
- then, it finds the second and binds it to fancybox
- and so on and so forth ... until it finds the last element and binds it to fancybox

... it sounds pretty obvious you may think but, when you do this :

```
$(".fancybox-img").fancybox().trigger("click");
```

... since you are chaining two methods, what the script actually does is :

- it finds the first element, binds it to fancybox AND then triggers a `click` event on that element
- then it finds the second, binds it to fancybox AND triggers a `click` event again on the second element
- and so on and so forth until it finds the last element, binds it to fancybox and triggers a `click` event once more

Since the last `click` was triggered on the last element (just right after it was bound to fancybox), then the last element is what you get in fancybox.

**The workaround**

To trigger your gallery from the first element (assuming this is what you want) use the `.eq()` method to filter what element should trigger a `click` event only like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox().eq(0).trigger("click");
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxm92/)**

Comment: Curiously I [answered](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fancybox/_9VNraZYGxQ/ukA3eQl_k94J) the same question back in 2010 ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing index: 2 from your settings...

Comment: i had the same problem without index setting, i also tried with different values, but no effect :(

Comment: willfried, are you sure there are no other fancybox settings elsewhere? Can you post a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: i edited my post with a jsfiddle link of my problem, thanks in advance

Comment: Well your html code looks a bit messy. There is an open "a" tag inside another "a" tag, then an "img" inside the second one... clean up your html code first, then we'll see again ;)